# nm-applet does not list own hotspot after having disconnected from it

Tags: linux, networkmanager

I created a hotspot (to share my LAN network over WLAN) using nm-applet and it works quite fine.
However, after disconnecting from my own hotspot (= stop being access point for other devices), I cannot reconnect any more because it disappeared from the list of available WIFI networks.
Only after restarting the network-manager service using `systemctl restart NetworkManager`, my hotspot gets listed again (and again disappears after disconnecting).
Can someone give me a hint on why this happens? I encountered the problem system-independent on Debian stable (xfce) and Fedora 34 (i3-wm).

Thanks a lot!